# php form don't add in the database

Tags: php, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTuGr.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6WBu.png)
**
**hello i have created a form whene i have used  php for the dynamic part were i click o submit there is nothing in the table in phpmyadmin i dont know too much php it's my first time thank you for your help**

** i have tried everything  it doesen't work i don't know **

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4qOo.png)

Comment: We can't work with images of code.

Comment: Start by enabling error reporting; you have errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error somewhere in the code. When you run the code, you are echo'ing `$query`, so what I suggest you do is take that SQL query that prints to your screen, and run it through phpMyAdmin directly. It'll either add it to the database, or tell you if there are errors in the query itself (think along the lines of typos in column names, etc.)

If an error is displayed in phpMyAdmin, then determine whether the typo (or whatever the error is) is in the database itself, or in the PHP code.

If it adds to the database, with no errors reported, then it's not with the SQL query.

I'd also suggest removing `action="./"` from the FORM element. I'm also not seeing an end to the FORM element. I'd suggest adding one.

And if none of that works, I'd suggest opening up your developer console in your browser, clicking the submit button, and seeing if the POST variables are passed in the Network section of the developer console.